# Apply a function to a data frame with numeric objects and print decimal points/trailing zeroes

Tags: r

I have a data frame with numeric objects from a contingency table in it:

```
x=sample(c(0,1),100,replace=T)
y=sample(c(0,1),100,replace=T)
my_table=table(x,y)
x.true=sum(my_table[2,])
y.true=sum(my_table[,2])
x.true.y.true=my_table[2,2]
x.true.y.false=my_table[2,1]
x.false.y.true=my_table[1,2]
x.false.y.false=my_table[1,1]
my_df=data.frame(x.true,y.true,
                 x.true.y.true,x.true.y.false,
                 x.false.y.true,x.false.y.false)
```

I want to print decimal points/trailing zeroes, but sprintf() does not work because it turns the elements into characters:

```
> sprintf('%.3f',my_df)
[1] "43.000" "55.000" "22.000" "21.000" "33.000" "24.000"
```

Wrapping it in as.numeric does not work either because it just truncates the zeroes again!

```
> as.numeric(sprintf('%.3f',my_df))
[1] 43 55 22 21 33 24
```

Even format.data.frame() does not work!

```
> format.data.frame(my_df,nsmall=5)
  x.true y.true x.true.y.true x.true.y.false x.false.y.true x.false.y.false
1     43     55            22             21             33              24
```

How do I force my data frame made of numeric objects to print decimal points/trailing zeroes?

Answer (score 1):

**First**, `sprintf()` will return a character vector, as it says in the function vignette:

> A wrapper for the C function sprintf, that returns a character vector containing a formatted combination of text and variable values.

**Second**, your data frame is made up of numeric objects, as you correctly stated, so you cannot get decimal points. You have two options:

1. wrap all of the objects in the data frame in an `as.double()` function and then use format.data.frame
2. apply as.double() to the elements of the data frame and then use format.data.frame

**Option 1** is quick and dirty and might work for your data:

```
my_df=data.frame(as.double(x.true),as.double(y.true),
                 as.double(x.true.y.true),as.double(x.true.y.false),
                 as.double(x.false.y.true),as.double(x.false.y.false))
format.data.frame(my_df,nsmall=5)
```

However, this might become very tedious if you have more data. You would have to type the wrapping function a lot of times!

**Option 2** is a bit more complex, but it is scalable.

You might suspect that you cannot use `apply()` on a data frame, and you would be right. To get around this, you have to turn it into a matrix, apply the function, transpose it, turn it back into a data frame, format it, and then give it its names back:

```
my_df2=format.data.frame(as.data.frame(t(apply(as.matrix(my_df),1,function(x) as.double(x)))),nsmall=5)
names(my_df2)=names(my_df)
my_df2
```